# A unit of language, consisting of one or more spoken sounds? Inexorably!

Tags: word, lateral-thinking, english, anagram

With great economy and without superfluous, exaggerated, flowery speech, please elucidate how to determine clearly and precisely what the beautiful, ornate, stupendous Word Of The Day is.

- My extreme wisdom was extracted from this common herb.
- A mechanic-turned-veterinarian who only works on arboreal primates.
- An pivotal, voiceless piece of music.
- I can't believe how small her makeup case is!
- My computer is on its last legs.
- The doorbell was extremely vigilant.
- Just go through the rear sliding glass doors to find Australia.
- I'll have a ribcage shot, and I'll chase it with a spinal cord.
- A firmly held opinion regarding religion.

Comment: Are the doubled words in the final line of the bounty (i.e. 'Somebody somebody should should receive receive a a prize prize.') important?

Comment: @ZanyG No, not really, that was just a little hint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the Word of the Day is

> Bombastic

As hinted at by Chowzen and suggested by Bard it seems like

> All the answers are the same word repeated

My extreme wisdom was extracted from this common herb.

> Sage sage

A mechanic-turned-veterinarian who only works on arboreal primates.

> Monkey monkey (as suggested by Bard)

An pivotal, voiceless piece of music.

> Instrumental instrumental

I can't believe how small her makeup case is!

> Compact compact

My computer is on its last legs.

> Terminal terminal

The doorbell was extremely vigilant.

> Alert alert (pointed out by jafe in the comments)

Just go through the rear sliding glass doors to find Australia.

> Outback out back

I'll have a ribcage shot, and I'll chase it with a spinal cord.

> Blowback blow back?

A firmly held opinion regarding religion.

> Belief belief

To get the Word of the Day

> Take the first letter of each answer **SMICTAOBB** and construct the anagram - **BOMBASTIC**. 
>  Bombastic means *high-sounding but with little meaning* which is essentially the description in the title and first paragraph of the riddle.

Comment: This is the right direction! +1

Comment: Of your existing answers, only the computer one isn't right; won't help with the anagram.

Comment: The vigilant doorbell could be rot13[nyreg]

Comment: @jafe, yes I think you are right.

Comment: IDK if this helps or not, but each answer is meant to be rot13{gjb gjb jbeqf jbeqf)

Comment: @Chowzen Having read your comment and Bard's answer I've updated with what I think is the answer.

Comment: You got it! Couple of notes: People are known to say things like rot13(V'yy unir n juvfxrl jvgu n jngre *onpx*) giving (onpx onpx). Also, the title was supposed to elicit rot13("Jbeq?" "Jbeq!") :) I'll rummage through my box full of checkmarks and add one to this answer when I find one.

Answer (score 3):

Partial:

My adventurous guess:

> all lines refer to the same word. The word was OUTBACK

An pivotal, voiceless piece of music.

> 4'33" by John Cage? this may contradict with the answer though

Just go through the rear sliding glass doors to find Australia.

> Outback (@hexomino)

I'll have a ribcage shot, and I'll chase it with a spinal cord.

> Outback (Out of the back)

Suspicious stuff:

> anagram tag???

Comment: [she says it best](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MF283pORG2E) :)

Answer (score 3):

Hoping to build on hexomino's answer and the hint

My extreme wisdom was extracted from this common herb.

> A sage Sage

A mechanic-turned-veterinarian who only works on arboreal primates.

> A monkey monkey? (as in grease monkey perhaps)

An pivotal, voiceless piece of music.

> This is an "instrumental instrumental"

I can't believe how small her makeup case is!

> A compact compact

My computer is on its last legs.

> A bored board? (as in motherboard)

The doorbell was extremely vigilant.

> An alert alert

Just go through the rear sliding glass doors to find Australia.

> The outback out back

I'll have a ribcage shot, and I'll chase it with a spinal cord.

> Now this is really reaching but a cordial cord y'all?

A firmly held opinion regarding religion.

> A faith faith (faithful faith?)

Overall all of these words are :

> Homonyms/homogrpahs